# Dumping results to a file. [Python]

Tags: python, json, file, attributes

I have kind of completed a task that my teacher set which was to generate attributes for a user that entered their name. I have used Json to write to a file from a list, though he said we was not allowed to import anything apart from 'math' and 'random'. I can't find any other ways of writing a list to a file. Could someone be kind enough to help me with this as I am really stuck.
He is the code.

```
import random
import math
import json

def attributes():
    return math.floor((random.randint(1,12)/random.randint(1,4))+10)

skill=[]
strength=[]
name=[]
result= {"Name" : name,"Strength" : strength,"Skill" : skill}

game=True

while game==True:
    nameinput = str(input('Enter your name. '))

    name.append(nameinput)
    skill.append(attributes())
    strength.append(attributes())
    print("Name:", name,"\nStrength", strength,"\nSkill", skill)

    g = open("Attributes.txt", "w")
    json.dump(result, g)
    g.close()
```

Comment: why not just `g.write("data=%s"%result)` ... that should work fine for this type of data

Answer (score 0):

Open your file as you did, then just use the `str` function to make a string from your `result` array and write it into the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
g = open("Attributes.txt", "a")
print >> g, result
g.close()
```